# How to rearrange columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to find the cumulative sum of elements of a column in another column using excel?

If yes please guide me.

Still on excel, I would like to know if it is possible to arrange elements of in an increasing or decreasing manner by comparing it's corresponding values?
For instance I would have liked excel to rearrange the names of my students by going by their marks scored

Comment: Have you tried using Excel's sort function?

Comment: -1, you've got two different questions here.  For the SU format, you should edit it into a single question and ask your second question separately. Also, please note what version of Excel you're using and what you've tried and why it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear - but if I understand correctly, in the first part you are asking how to find the sum of elements in one column and to have that sum appear in a different column. simply use the standard =SUM() function in the column where you want the answer to appear & reference inside the parens the column where the elements are.

As for your second question - have you tried simply doing a Sort on the column with the "corresponding values"? E.G., if you sort according to the marks scored column it should do what you want.

In the future, I think it's a better practice to ask only one question in each post.